# Find the radius and the interval of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^3}{(n^2+1)^2}\left(\frac{4x-3}{x}\right)^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification, power-series

I was asked to find the radius and the interval of convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^3}{(n^2+1)^2}\left(\frac{4x-3}{x}\right)^n \:,x\neq 0 \: (1)$.

This is my 1st try:

Let $X=\frac{4x-3}{x}=4-\frac{3}{x}$, then the given series  $(1)$ becomes $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^3}{(n^2+1)^2}X^n\: (2)$. We have

$\rho=\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^3\left(\frac{n^2+1}{(n+1)^2+1}\right)^2|X|=|X|,$
so we get convergence if $\rho<1\Rightarrow |X|<1\Rightarrow -1<X<1$, and the radius of convergence of the  series $(2)$ is $R=1$.

Now I check the endpoints. At $X=1$, the series $(2)$ becomes  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^3}{(n^2+1)^2}$, this series is divergent (by using the limit comparison test with the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$). At $X=-1$, the series $(2)$ becomes $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{n^3}{(n^2+1)^2}$, this series is convergent (by using Leibniz criterion).

Thus, the radius of convergence of the series $(2)$ is $R=1$ and the interval of convergence of the series $(2)$ is $[-1;1)$.

But $X=\frac{4x-3}{x}=4-\frac{3}{x}$ and $-1\leq X<1$, so we have $-1\leq 4-\frac{3}{x}<1 \Rightarrow \frac{3}{5}\leq x<1$.

I get stuck here. Is it reasonable to say that the interval convergence of the series $(1)$ is $[\frac{3}{5};1)$? And how about the radius of convergence of the series $(1)$? I don't think $R=1$ is reasonable! So it's very nice to see your suggestions to solve this problem! Thanks.

Comment: I see no flaw in your arguments. Note though that while the series (1) is a power series (in the variable X), the series (2) is *not a power series* (in the variable $x$) so there is no generic reason why it should have a radius or interval of convergence. In your case the points for which it converges still form an interval, but I would see that as a lucky coincidence. Note how the "centre" $X=0$ of (1) corresponds to $x=3/4$ in (2) which is no longer the "centre" of the interval $[3/5, 1)$.

Comment: Sorry, I flipped what you call (1) and (2) in my previous comment, it's the other way around.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg "Note how the "centre" X=0 of (2) corresponds to x=3/4
 in (1) which is no longer the "centre" of the interval [3/5,1)", yeah this is why I have doubts about my results. As you said, since the series (1) is not a power series, then It is not suitable to define the radius of convergence, but the interval convergence is ok! So, in this case, I can say the interval of convergence of the series (1) is $[\frac{3}{5};1)$, and can't say anything about the radius of convergence! Am I right when understanding it in that way?

Comment: I don't know. Depends on who asked you to solve this. I personally would not call anything "radius of convergence" of the series (1).

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, I would've solved this problem in the same manner, so I'll just comment on the ending tidbits:

---

> Is it reasonable to say that the interval convergence of the series $(1)$ is $[\frac{3}{5};1)$?

Yes. More generally, it can be shown that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n$ has interval of convergence $|x|<R$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n (f(x))^n$ has interval of convergence $|f(x)|<R$. This is an idea you exploited here.

*(This is ignoring that the original series is not a power series, and hence need not have something that cleanly lines up with notions of intervals or radii of convergence.)*

---

> And how about the radius of convergence of the series $(1)$? I don't think $R=1$ is reasonable!

Also true, this would not be a reasonable claim, since the interval has length $2/5$.

But that means that the radius of convergence is simply half of that, at $1/5$, with center at the midpoint $4/5$.

However, this is strictly in the sense of the real-number context. For power series with a radius of convergence $R$, it actually will converge for all ***complex*** numbers $z$ with $|z|<R$, not merely just the real numbers. This renders its region of convergence an open disk (plus perhaps some of the boundary). However, that is not the case for your series since it's not a power series, and in the complex numbers it will not converge on a disk but instead on an oval-shaped domain (as noted by Torsten Schoeneberg below), so the notion of a "radius of convergence" does not cleanly translate here.

Hence, to speak of a "radius of convergence" for this series only applies in a limiting context at best, and is thus a bit of an abuse of terminology.

Comment: You say you ignore that the set $\lbrace x: |f(x) < R|\}$ is, in general, no longer an interval. But do people seriously, in case it happens to be an interval (like here), just call half of its length the series' "radius of convergence"? That seems like an abuse of terminology to me.

Comment: I don't know if they do, but I don't see a reason why not. It is an interval.

Comment: "Radius" in radius of convergence is used because in complex numbers, the natural setting for all this, we have disks of conv. for power series about a point. This thing is not a power series, and its region of convergence is kind of an oval: The image of the disk of radius $1$ around $4$, mapped under $z \mapsto 3/z$; e.g. the centre of the original ball gets mapped to 3/4 which is not the midpoint of the interval $(3/5, 1)$. One can cook up examples which converge e.g. on a union of several disjoint intervals. "Radius" of convergence is a misused term once the series is not a power series.

Comment: Oh, good point, I totally forgot about the complex-number context.

Answer (score -2):

Denote \begin{equation}a_{n}=\frac{n^{3}}{(n^{2} + 1)^{2}}\end{equation} and compute the upper limit of it under a square, when n goes to infinity, then divide 1 by that limit, you'll get the radius of convergence. You can find more here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem